# How to use reactContext and getJSModule in a service?

Tags: android, react-native, react-context

I have a `ReactModule` which it turn starts a `ForegroundService` which registers and listens for some events. Once one of the events happens I want to send a message to the `React-Native` level using `DeviceEventManagerModule`...

```
reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
        .emit(DRIVING_EVENT, params);
```

The service has it's own context, and it doesn't have the `getJSModule` method there.
Is there a way I can get the `reactContext` inside my service?

I think that I can use `Broadcast`s to send events from the service to the calling module, but if the application is swiped out from recent apps - will the module still be able to listen to the broadcasts?

**Update:**
To get the react-context in a non react class you can do the following:

```
  ReactApplication application = (ReactApplication)(context.getApplicationContext());
        ReactContext reactContext = application.getReactNativeHost()
                .getReactInstanceManager()
                .getCurrentReactContext();
```

Then, you can use the context to emit messages like that:

```
       reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                        .emit("your-key","your data");
```

If for some reason react context is null you can request it like that:

```
ReactApplication application = (ReactApplication)(context.getApplicationContext());
application
                .getReactNativeHost()
                .getReactInstanceManager()
                .addReactInstanceEventListener(new ReactInstanceManager.ReactInstanceEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext context) {

                    }
                });
            application.getReactNativeHost()
                    .getReactInstanceManager()
                    .createReactContextInBackground();
```

Comment: @NiccolòCaselli see updates. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class YourModuleName extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    
  private final ReactApplicationContext _reactContext;
    
  public YourModuleName(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        _reactContext = reactContext;
  }

  // Your code here...

}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't need to create a module. I want to have a context inside my service that can communicate directly with the react native layer.